# Laravel 5.2 insert an array at once and update if exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to insert an array at once and i also want to update if exists. But i get this error.

```
$jobs = array();

//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
foreach ($links as $link){

        $data = get_job_info($link);

        $jobs[] = [
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'full_desc' => $data['desc'],
            'to_date' => $data['date'],
            'ad_type' => 'fb'
        ];

    }
}

DB::table('customer_position')->insert($jobs);
```

Comment: Why you call `table()` method from `FbPosition` model? why not use `DB` facade?

Comment: @Rifki that is correct, but how do I check if exists?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `updateOrCreate()` method, lets say you have list of jobs in `$jobs` variable:

```
foreach($jobs as $job) {
    MyModel::updateOrCreate(['title' => $job['title']], $job);
}
```

It just like telling Laravel that if a job with the specified `title` already exists, update it. Otherwise save a new job to database.

In case you get mass assignment exception you have to define the `$fillable` column as @AlexeyMezenin said.

If want you can create a new static method on your model:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    ...

    public static function bulkInsertOrUpdate(array $jobs)
    {
        foreach($jobs as $job) {
            static::updateOrCreate(['title' => $job['title']], $job);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `MyModel::bulkInsertOrUpdate($jobs)` in your controller.

Comment: @Rifiki is it not a way to do this on the full array?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such way unless there is `DB::table('mytable')->insert($array)` but since you need check existences it wont work.

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg see my edited answer if you want to do it without having to loop `$jobs` on your controller method.

Comment: It returns and error. syntax error, unexpected 'bulkInsertOrUpdate' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg My bad sorry I missed `function` part see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model to use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature:

```
$customerPosition = CustomerPosition::firstOrNew(['id' => $id]);
$customerPosition->fill($jobs)->save();
```

Or shortcut for this - `updateOrCreate()`

Both will just update or insert one model.

Also, to use mass assignment feature, add to `$fillable` array all properties you want to save:

```
class CustomerPosition extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'full_desc', 'to_date', 'ad_type'];
```

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that part, I've updated my code, which updates existing model or creates a new model.

Comment: doesn't this just insert one row at a time? Is it not possible to insert a whole array?

Comment: This is what i dont get yet. Assume i dont want duplicate titles, $customerPosition = CustomerPosition::firstOrNew(['title' => 'what do i write here?']);

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg, it will just insert or update one row.